# HTTPGet unicode characters appearing in response String

Tags: java, http-get

I have a utility used for integrating data and have run into an issue when special characters are used such as "Ã". Below is the method in question where the issue comes in. The response is from an API and is in xml format.

```
    protected String getStringHttpContent(URI url, Map<String,String> headerParameters) throws IOException
    {
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
    for(String parameter : headerParameters.keySet())
            request.setHeader(parameter, headerParameters.get(parameter));

        CloseableHttpResponse response = getClient().execute(request);
        dumpHeaders(response);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        String output;
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(output);
        }
     response.close();
        return sb.toString();

    }
```

The result of njÃmientill in the response string is njÃ¤mientill. I've tried changing the encoding, but result remains the same. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked what character encoding - if any - the remote party indicates via the response headers?

Comment: Yes, the encoding is coming over as gzip. I've attempted to account for this by adding the appropriate header for gzip, but result remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are using UTF-8 encoding end-to-end (through the whole chain). This includes you web pages and user input if it comes from a html form (for example), setting UTF-8 on pages, web services (web.xml, sun-web.xml or so). Also Inbound HttpRequest should include the header attribute "charset", eg. "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 ". The way your configure server-side and client-side depends on the technologies you use (which I don't know).

**EDIT**: regarding your comment, even if you are the client you should set the content-type to define which type of content you expect from the server (as this one may be able to serve different contents at the same URL).

Please try configure your HttpGet with:

```
request.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/xml; charset=utf-8");
```

or (if the server is quite old):

```
request.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
```

Better, maybe specify the accept header together with the accepted charset:

```
request.setHeader("Accept-Charset", "utf-8");
request.setHeader("Accept", "application/xml");
```

If none of these works I suggest you show your Postman query here or do a Wireshark capture to see the actual request and response, plus also list the content of the *headerParameters* map. Otherwise we cannot help you more (as the rest of your code looks good, to my opinion).

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that many times, but the result stays the same. I don't have access to the server providing the response as it's at a client site, but using a simple API get tool, such as postman, I don't have this problem.

Comment: Thanks again, unfortunately the response doesn't change. In regards to the map, for this request, it simply has "Accept Content: application/xml". Below is the header output from postman minus the cookies.

Content-Encoding →gzip
Content-Type →application/xml
Date →Sun, 22 Oct 2017 16:30:00 GMT
Server →ServiceNow
Strict-Transport-Security →max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains
Transfer-Encoding →chunked
X-Is-Logged-In →true

Comment: Assuming that you have put "Accept: application/xml" and "Accept-Charset: utf-8" in your HttpGet request and still have issue decoding the returned string as utf-8.. what if the server API was not actually speaking to you in UTF-8? :)  (eg. ISO-8859-1?)  Also as you receive an XML reply, what does the XML header tell you? Can you confirm the presence of  <... encoding="UTF-8" ..> ?